# Getting the overall return value of a function within a loop

Tags: php, return-value

What I am doing is looping over an array and running a function on each value of the array (the function returns true on success, false on error). I would like to return false if any of the calls inside the loop returned false, but I want the whole loop to be processed.

Probably easier to explain with code:

```
foreach($this->_cacheLocations as $cacheId)
{
    $this->deleteCache($cacheId);
}

return true/false depending on whether anything failed above;
```

I'd prefer not to introduce a variable to keep track of any falses if possible. Eg, I'd prefer not to do the following:

```
$result = true;
foreach($this->_cacheLocations as $cacheId)
{
    $_result = $this->deleteCache($cacheId);
    if(!$_result) $result = false;
}

return $result;
```

Is there a fancy way to do this or should I just do it the second way?

Comment: There is no simpler way to do it, except like Pascal's single variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to track multiple return results together, you're unfortunately going to need a variable.  If you didn't want it to be a local variable in the scope of your loop, you could create an object property that was set by `deleteCache()`, but unless it's being used by other functions as well, a local variable is the cleanest solution.

Assuming that `$this->deleteCache()` always returns `true` or `false`, you could shorten it up to something like this:

```
$result = true;
foreach($this->_cacheLocations as $cacheId)
{
        $result = $this->deleteCache($cacheId) && $result;
}
return $result;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly cleaner than what I had.

Comment: note that in most languages, the `&&` operator short-circuits, so after the first `false` value, the loop won't call the function anymore.

Comment: Excellent point Javier, you are correct. I reversed the order of operations to fix it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with a variable, like you did in your second portion of code -- at least, that's what I do in that kind of situations.

If you want to eliminate one temporary variable, you could use :

```
$result = true;
foreach($this->_cacheLocations as $cacheId)
{
        if (!$this->deleteCache($cacheId)) {
            $result = false;
        }
}
return $result;
```

But the idea remains the same as what you posted.

Comment: agreed, no hacks around this one.